SPC564L70L3 Core voltage generation
I am reviewing some schematics where a SPC564L70L3 MCU is used, and I noticed that it uses the BCTRL pin (pin47 in the 100-pin package) to generate the 1.2 V for the core, using an external NPN transistor.
I have seen in the datasheet this device has 2 high power regulators to power the cores, one of them is internal (HPREG1) and the other is the external one, controlled by BCTRL pin (HPREG2).
As far as I understand, both are for the same function, just power the core of the MCU, and if you connect a NPN transistor in BCTRL pin, the internal HPREG1 regulator is disabled, and if there is no transistor in BCTRL pin, the HPREG1 is used to power the core instead...
This makes me ask the following question: Which is the difference between using the internal one and the external one? If I can use the internal one, why should I use the external one, and use additional components to do the same function?
I could not find the difference in the datasheet or reference manual. The info about HPREG1 and HPREG2 can be found in section 40.3 (page 1170) of the reference manual called “RM0342 SPC56XL70xx 32-bit MCU family built on the embedded Power Architecture®”.
If any of you can clarify me a little bit more regarding this topic, I would be really pleased!!
SPC564L70L3 MCU

The SPC564L70L3 datasheet has the following in section 3.9 Voltage regulator electrical characteristics:

HPREG1 uses an internal ballast to support the core current. HPREG2 is used only when external NPN transistor is present on board to supply core current. The SPC56XL70 always powers up using HPREG1 if an external NPN transistor is present. Then the SPC56XL70 makes a transition from HPREG1 to HPREG2. This transition is dynamic. Once HPREG2 is fully operational, the controller part of HPREG1 is switched off.

Which made me think having using the external HPREG2 reduces the power dissipation of the die and therefore allows the die to have a lower temperature.
The datasheet Table 1. SPC56XL70/SPC56X64 device summary has the following related features:



Category
Feature
Description




Supply
Device power supply
3.3 V with integrated bypassable ballast transistor External ballast transistor not needed for bare die


Temperature
Temperature range (junction)
–40 to 150 °C


Temperature
Ambient temperature range usingexternal ballast transistor (LQFP)
–40 to 125 °C



Section 1.5.40 Voltage regulator / power management unit (PMU) has:

Single high supply required: nominal 3.3 V both for packaged and Known Good Die option

Packaged option requires external ballast transistor due to reduced dissipation capacity at high temperature but can use embedded transistor if power dissipation is maintained within package dissipation capacity (lower frequency of operation)
Known Good Die option uses embedded ballast transistor as dissipation capacity is increased to reduce system cost


Therefore, using the external HPREG2 is about managing the power dissipation and therefore temperature of the die.
Given the SPC564L70L3 targets automotive SIL3/ASILD chassis and safety applications, the application might need to be certified for a high operating temperature.
